# Iterating over and comparing properties of two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, javascript-objects

I have set up a HBS helper which takes in two arrays of objects (users privileges). What I want to do is compare them and inject back into the template the privileges the user does and doesn't have.

Presently I can compare the names of the privileges with the following code:

```
hbs.registerHelper('selected', function(option, value){
  var i;
  var j;
  var privName;
  var userPriv;

  var privObj = new Object();
  var privArray = [];

  for(i in option){
    console.log('each ' + JSON.stringify(option[i]));
    privName = option[i].privname;

    for (y in value){
      if(privName == value[y].privname){

      userPriv = value[y].privname;
      console.log('user has the following privileges', value[y].privname);

      privObj = new Object();
      privObj.name = userpriv;
      privObj.id = value[y]._id;
      privObj.state = 'selected';
      privArray.push(privObj);

    } else if (privName != value[y].privname){
      console.log('user doesnt have priv ', privName);

      privObj = new Object();
      privObj.name = option[i].privname;
      privObj.id = option[i].id;
      privObj.state = '';
      privArray.push(privObj);

    }

  }
}

console.log('privileges array ', privArray);
return privArray;

});
```

This works OK when the user only has one privilege, however when the user has more than one, for example two privileges, it returns the privileges twice. If the user has 3, thrice and so on. I know this is because the array is looping again because their are 2, 3 etc in the .length. However I can't seem to find an adequate solution.

Any help?

P.S. it would be nice if the `Array.includes()` method allowed you to search object properties.

Comment: Why are you adding both types (with and without privileges) to the `privArray`? Also, why are you copying each object to a new one? Why not just `privArray.push(value[y])`?

Comment: Because I want to return all privileges and then in the template highlight those "selected" and display privileges the user doesn't have unhighlighted,

I am creating a new object because I want to add a new property called privObj.state, so that in the template I can differentiate those the user has and those the user doesn't. I'm sure there is a better way...

Comment: I can't argue much because I don't know nothing about _hbs_, but seeing your code I think my answer should work

Comment: id did! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem creating new objects the way you did is that for each property you add to your *privilege-entity* you will have to return to that function and set that property as well. You can instead just add/alter the `state` property of the existing objects:

```
hbs.registerHelper('selected', function(option, value) {
    var names = option.map(function(opt) {
        return opt.privname;
    });  
    value.forEach(function(val) {
        val.state = names.indexOf(val.privname) >= 0 ? 'selected' : '';
    });
    return value;
});
```

Basically:

- The variable `names` is being mapped to be an array only with the privnames. You can check by using `console.log(names)`.
- The `Array.forEach()` function is helpful in this case because you just need to iterate over each object inside `value` and set its `state`-property.
- To check if the `privname` exists, you just need to check the index in the previous `names`-mapped-array. For such a simple thing I used ternary operator (`?:`).
- Finally, you `return value`, which is the array containing the objects you had updated.

Comment: Glad to see it helped :) .. I will update with some explanation

Comment: I've updated... You can [mark my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/321253) if it has worked for you